# boost serialization and register_type

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, export

I have a problem in an application i'm doing. I need to serialize some packets using boost serialization. According to the documentation, one can use `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY` and `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT` respectively into .hpp and .cpp files to be able to use polymorphic base pointer to serialize derived class.

So here is what I have:

.hpp: containaing my class declaration and finaly the `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(mynamespace::mypacket)`

.cpp: containing my class definition and the `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(mynamespace::mypacket)`

Everything runs fine till this point but when needing to serialize I get a bad_alloc error.

I worked arround this problem by explicitly calling the method `register_type<mypacket>()` on the archive i need to use.

But here is my question : Is the EXPORT* of boost meant to avoid calls to register_type method or am I doing something wrong? I kind of feel like doing twice the same work in my code, but more than that I don't see any advantage of using export key + implement if we still have to use register_type on archive after!

I read some other posts here and elsewhere, it seems I'm not the only one to experiment the problem, but I have not found any answer yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

i figured out how to avoid calling register_type on archive. For those who might be interested, it is needed to do template serialization specialization as well as exporting key + implement.

So here is what your .hpp should look like :

- class declaration (mynamespace::myclass)
- class export : `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(mynamespace::myclass)`

And in the cpp:

- class definiton
- class export : `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(mynamespace::myclass)`
- AND : serialize() member specialization on the archive you need to use, for each class :

`template void mynamespace::mypacket::serialize(boost::archive::text_iarchive& arch, const unsigned int version);`

`template void mynamespace::mypacket::serialize(boost::archive::text_oarchive& arch, const unsigned int version);`

Where boost::archive::text_(i/o)archive should be replaced with whatever kind of boost archive you are using.

In hope it will help someone someday (this is clearly written in the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#dlls), but i must have missed it till today...)

Comment: Thank you!!! I'd give you +10 if I could, you saved my life! It's a whole day that I was having some classes whose `boost::serialization::extended_type_info::get_key()` returned NULL. Just some for classes, in other ones it was working perfectly and it was returning the stringified name correctly. And this was the reason! I didn't split the `EXPORT` process in two phases! I was just using `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(CLASS)` in my `.cpp` files, in place of `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(CLASS)` in the `.h`and `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(CLASS)` in the `.cpp`. **THANK YOU AGAIN!!!** :)

Comment: I get `undefined reference to void myclass::serialize(...)` if I do the same thing with you and the doc.