# multiple definition boost serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I use a library (https://github.com/tipaldi/flirtlib) that uses boost serialization on derived polymorphic classes. My problem is that I need to include the header in different places and this causes the linking error :
multiple definition of `boost::archive::detail::extra_detail::init_guid`

In the .h of the class the boost export macro is : `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(BetaGrid)`

The solution I found suggests to replace this macro with `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(BetaGrid)` in the .h and `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(BetaGrid)` in the .cpp. Using this solution, the linking works but I get runtime error saying that the derived class is not registered.

I tried many other Macro combinations but nothing I tried works.

This issue with the boost serialization is here since many years now...

Comment: Why would you `//` the macro in the cpp file?

Comment: And did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707500/boost-serialization-and-register-type ?

Comment: Remove the `//`. `//` makes it a comment. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Sorry. It was a tipo. In the code the macro is not commented. I'll update my question

Comment: @yakk yes I tried the solution in the link you give

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My crystal ball says that you missed the documentation that states you have to include the headers for all archive types that you are going to be using at the point of exporting macros.

From the docs: [Exporting Class Serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#export)

> **BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT** in the same source module that includes any of the archive class headers will instantiate code required to serialize polymorphic pointers of the indicated type to the all those archive classes. **If no archive class headers are included, then no code will be instantiated.**

Comment: Thanks, I'll double check the includes.